# JAVA - ternary nested in jsp

Tags: java, conditional-operator

I don't understand why my ternary doesn't work ! fmt:message is dynamic translate text and I'm using jQuery.

```
<c:forTokens var="key" varStatus="status" items="AdministrationApplicationSMTPSMTPSendMethodSendAs,AdministrationApplicationSMTPSMTPSendMethodReplyTo" delims = ",">
    <option ${ ( bean.getProperties().getApplicationSmtpSendMethod().equals('SendMethodSendAs') ? 'selected' : ( bean.getProperties().getApplicationSmtpSendMethod().equals('SendMethodReplyTo') ? 'selected' : '' ) ) }>
        <fmt:message key="${ key }"/>
    </option>
</c:forTokens>
```

If you have any leads? I'm a taker...

Use that is work, my option select is target but with other example I think equals return only false.. :S

```
<c:forTokens var="key" varStatus="status" items="AdministrationApplicationSMTPSMTPSendMethodSendAs,AdministrationApplicationSMTPSMTPSendMethodReplyTo" delims = ",">
    <option ${ bean.getProperties().getApplicationSmtpSendMethod().equals('SendMethodSendAs') ? 'selected' : '' } ${ bean.getProperties().getApplicationSmtpSendMethod().equals('SendMethodReplyTo') ? 'selected' : '' }>
        <fmt:message key="${ key }"/>
    </option>
</c:forTokens>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Doesn't work as in "unexpected result" or as in "doesn't even compile"?

Comment: Compilation is good, just my 'selected' on <option> take the first <option> on <select> list by default.. but with the second exemple (2 ternary in the same option) is good, but not "good practice"..

Comment: Sorry, just to be clear, it means that the first option actually has the `selected` attribute or just that it visually the default selection? Also, have you checked that there's only one `selected` `option`?

Comment: None of this is jquery.  I've removed the tag.

Comment: I don't know precisely why my ternary doesn't work, if it's because of jquerry and the "equal" method or if it's my JSP file that doesn't support the syntax :S

Comment: Why do you think this has anything to do with jQuery? As has be pointed out there's nothing remotely related to it in your code